# MongoDB Pymongo Ubuntu - time issues

Tags: mongodb, datetime, ubuntu

I have an app that communicates to a MongoDB DB through a REST API running flask. I'm seeing time readings within the App to be 5 hours off - which makes me think its a time zone issue.

Ubuntu is showing me the correct time - Its formatted as per EST. Though, MongoDB - which I dont think has any awareness of timezone is displaying incorrect local time (even in UTC). When running db.serverStatus() i get a reply back saying:

```
"localTime" : ISODate("2013-12-13T21:15:16.663+19:00"),
```

Its about 9:15pm here on 12/12. So UTC, should be around 2:15am. I was expecting to see:

ISODate("2013-12-13T02:15:16.663+05:00").

Is my assumption correct on the expected ISODate object? How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the MongoDB shell is reporting dates correctly.

```
ISODate("2013-12-13T21:15:16.663+19:00")
```

You said is about 2:15 AM, Dec 13 at your location, in UTC. That is 21:15 on a +19 hours offset, which is what MongoDB shows. I'm not sure why it is displaying the date with that offset?!?

Since you're the `pymongo` driver, take a look at the `tz_aware` option of the database connection classes. The default value is `False`, which means you get naive dates on your application. Set to `True` to get timezone aware dates.

Comment: yes, your correct. In pymongo I'm inserting timestamp's without using tz_aware - I'm using datetime.datetime.now() - which is incorrect. I changed that to datetime.datetime.utcnow(). With that change, I'm seeing the correct time in iOS.
Yea, the offset confuses me too - I dont see any config or anywhere else I can change that!
I moved the server onto UTC too - instead of EST

Comment: actually.
Flask-PyMongo always uses timezone-aware datetime objects. That is, it sets the tz_aware parameter to True when creating a connection. The timezone of datetime objects returned from MongoDB will always be UTC. Which confuses me a little to as why datetime.datetime.now() was not being converted to UTC

Comment: solved..

Robomongo - was doing that! It was converting dates before displaying them to me. Dang it.

Comment: Glad you solved it. BTW, on the Python side, `datetime.datetime.now()` gives you a naive object. Naive datetimes don't have timezone information, so they cannot be safely cast to aware objects. Probably, the driver is assuming your datetime objects are in UTC, and inserting them as is in the database, but they are in local time, causing the perceived 5 hours offset.